# React Routing Issues Deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, routes

I have a React application that uses Rails API for the backend. Everything works fine in development. However, once deployed to Heroku my routes fails upon manual refresh. The only route that does work is the Home route. You can find the app here .... `http://card-collector-app.herokuapp.com/`.

When you log in it takes you to the cards view page. But then if you do a manual refresh everything goes blank. Manual routing back to the home page works, but that is the only thing that does.

I would love some help if anyone has any ideas what's going on?

Here is the heroku log. As you can see, at first it finds the route. But then on a manual refresh it throws a routing error with status 404 with a whole bunch of other fatal errors.

```
2018-04-01T15:38:57.187873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/1/cards" host=card-collector-app.herokuapp.com request_id=6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c fwd="98.195.93.19" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=191 protocol=http
2018-04-01T15:38:57.183795+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-01T15:38:57.183477 #4]  INFO -- : [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] Started GET "/1/cards" for 98.195.93.19 at 2018-04-01 15:38:57 +0000
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185195+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-01T15:38:57.185127 #4] FATAL -- : [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c]   
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185519+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-01T15:38:57.185227 #4] FATAL -- : [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/1/cards"):
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185652+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-01T15:38:57.185545 #4] FATAL -- : [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c]   
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185783+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-01T15:38:57.185697 #4] FATAL -- : [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185786+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185788+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185790+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185792+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185794+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185795+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185797+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185799+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185801+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185804+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185802+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185806+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185807+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185809+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185811+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-cors-1.0.2/lib/rack/cors.rb:97:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185812+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185814+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185816+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185817+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185819+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
2018-04-01T15:38:57.185820+00:00 app[web.1]: [6d8a3f8f-2b2a-4ecd-98ad-1216c2eccd9c] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: can you show your `heroku log`?

Comment: updated my post with heroku logs

Comment: it is invoking rails routes i think when you reload the page?

Comment: Yea I'm pretty sure it has to do with being a single page app ( React ). I think I need to redirect all does to fallback to index.js ... But don't know how to successfully tell my app to do that.

Comment: I'm having the same bug with Symfony 4 + Heroku. The "/" page works, but the other ones not... Any solution?

Comment: I got it working with a hack solution... Not the best though. I used HashRouter instead of BrowsetRouter. This adds a # at the begging of your routes and when your controllers sees the # it automatically goes back and like at the root. It would, but kind of hacky.